# Add ProgressBar to the last cell on GridView while loading more data

Tags: android, gridview, progress-bar, footer, custom-cell

My app is based on a grid view that displays many images from a server.
I'm trying not to overload the server, so i want to display 20 images at a time, and when the user scrolls down, the app displays more images. 
i'm want to add an extra cell when the Gridview is at the bottom of the screen, and then to make it GONE when the server finished loading the extra images ,but i couldn't find a solution. here are pictures from h&m app - they managed to figure it out... i'm trying to build something very similar to what they doing.. 
[image: notice the little progress bar on the bottom right]
can anyone help me?
here is my code so far..
thanks!

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    private Context mContext;

    // ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public MyAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();            
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ProgressBar spinner;
        TextView Price;
        ImageView imageView;
        RelativeLayout Item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return mThumbIds[arg0];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        View grid = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_catalog, parent,
                    false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.spinner = (ProgressBar) grid
                    .findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            holder.Price = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.Item = (RelativeLayout) grid.findViewById(R.id.itemGrid);
            grid.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) grid.getTag();

        }
    //  SpinnerLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.Price.setText(String.valueOf(TheAdapterPrice[position]));
        imageLoader.displayImage(mThumbIds[position], holder.imageView,
                options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        holder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
        holder.Item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                BigSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        Catalog_Store.class);
                intent.putExtra("TheItem", mThumbIds[position]);
                intent.putExtra("PriceShirt", TheAdapterPrice[position]);
                // startActivity(intent);

                GetTheIDFromParseServers(intent, TheClassName,
                        mThumbIds[position]);
            }
        });
        TotalItemDisplay = getCount();
        if (continueScrollSelector == true) {
            if (position == TotalItemDisplay - 1) {

                //this method make the call to the server to add images
                AddMoreImages();
                // The ScrollSelector is basically how match pictures to
                // load every time the user
                // scrolls down
                ScrollSelector = ScrollSelector + MorePhotosToLoad;

            } else {

            }
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

Comment: Have You tried to use different items types instead of complex layout (which contains item and progress at the same time)? If so, can You specify, what is not working exactly?